# drupal 7 contextual filter views update

Tags: views

I updated views 3.0 to 3.7 and it broke a slideshow view that was setup with contextual filter to display certain content based off the url. Same setup just updated views if anyone can tell me why this does not work with the new views or how to make it work, would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please check if the slideshow that you are using will support with views 3.7

Comment: do you use views slideshow module?

Comment: Yes it is views slideshow module and i am not sure if it is compatible or not. There have been no issues about this in the views or views slideshow.

Comment: 1> Clear the site cache once
2> Un-install and install the view and slideshow modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track the issue to a change made in views module that was committed with 3.1 release. Contextual links statement was changed from 'OR' to 'AND' causing issues with the setup that was run with version 3.0.

http://drupal.org/node/1451218#comment-5980636